# Removing character duplication in a vector of strings

Tags: c++

I have a list of list of file names like:

```
{ {1234}, {15}, {1264}, {78} }
```

For example, `{1234}` is the collection of four names `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

I need a vector of strings with only one element including the unique occurrence of each file name: `{{12345678}}`

Here is my approach (which does not completely work):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void push_back_vec(std::vector<T>& v, Args&&... args)
{
    (v.push_back(args), ...);
}

vector<string> g(vector<string> a)
{
    vector<string> result;
    result.push_back( accumulate( a.begin(), a.end(), string("") ) );
    sort( result.begin(), result.end() );
    result.erase( unique( result.begin(), result.end() ), result.end() );
    return result;
}
```

But the elements of the output are neither sorted nor unique: `126412347815`

Comment: Think about the contents of `result` after that `push_back`.

Comment: @Rakete1111: I guess the problem is that `push_back` returns one string, and I need to eliminate duplicated chars of it, but the problem is that the string is in a vector.

Comment: @Rakete1111: I even tried to get `result[0]` as a string, remove its duplicates by `result.erase(std::unique(result.begin(), result.end()), result.end());` But the result is still wrong. What's wrong with it?...

Comment: You are still erasing and applying `std::unique` to  `result`, not `result[0]`. Really, just use `std::string result;` and sort + unique + erase that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a single number 126412347815 (and unique too)

```
result.push_back(accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), string("")));
```

The above accumulates into a single string

Use the below code to remove duplicate from string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<numeric>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void push_back_vec(std::vector<T>& v, Args&&... args)
{
    (v.push_back(args), ...);
}

int main()
{

    vector<string>x;
    push_back_vec(x, "123", "452", "321");

    string a = accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), string(""));

    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    auto end = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
    a.erase(end,a.end());
    std::cout << std::string(a.begin(), end) << '\n';

}

Output

12345
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: So how can I get rid of those repetitive characters? As I said what I need to get is `12345678`.